# Write a class named Calculator with a method int sum(String s)

Tags: java, string, while-loop

String s contains a set of integers separated by white space (blanks, tabs, or newlines). Return the sum of the integers.

You can use a Scanner object to solve this problem. Create a new Scanner(s) and store it in a variable, say in. Then, use in.hasNextInt() to control a while loop. Each iteration of the while loop uses in.nextInt() to get the next integer from the String s. Accumulate this integer into a variable and return that variable when the loop exits.

You may use a main method to test your method by creating an instance of the Calculator class and calling sum(…) with several combinations of values using that instance.

For example, sum(“3 4 5 27 3”) is 42.

I have written this so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  }

  public int sum(String s){
    int i = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(s);
    while (in.hasNextInt())  {        
        sum = sum + in.nextInt();     
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: what am missing? it compiles fine but I am not sure what to do to get the outcome of sum(" some numbers") = some number

Comment: Another "Do my homework" thingies...

Comment: Please do not post homework questions here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call the method from main and display the results make the `sum` method `static` and then call it and print the result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   System.out.println(sum("1 2 3"));

}
```

Comment: @RichardDisimoni No problem, accept the answer using the tick icon to the left if it solved your problem. You should read the question guidelines before asking any more questions though since you will get a better&faster result (and fewer down/close) votes if you ask clearer questions :)

Comment: thanks for the advice, I'm new to coding and getting overwhelmed fast

Comment: @RichardDisimoni No worries. Basically you need to drill down and identify the actual problem you have (i.e. in this case how do I display the results from my method call) and ask about that clearly rather than posting the full thing you are working on...you should also check the existing answers and do some web searches to try and answer the question yourself before posting.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(sum("1 2 3"));
    }

    public static int sum(String s){
        int i = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(s);
        while (in.hasNextInt())  {        
            sum = sum + in.nextInt();     
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```